# Customized search need to display name search result based on selected name

Tags: php, yii

I Implemented my project in Yii. i showing search results. based on differed table and different field value from table. it displaying very well.

i sent from controller post values and displaying values in view part.
it displaying only the id if i give name its not displaying and showing error. i added my code here. just check and tell where i need to be change accordingly my code.

```
<?php
if(isset($getval)){
    $as=$getval;
}else{
    $as="";
}
if(isset($course)){
    $as1=$course;
}else{
    $as1="";
}
if(isset($type)){
    $as3=$type;
}else{
    $as3="";
}
if(isset($cuisine)){
    $as4=$cuisine;
}else{
    $as4="";
}
if(isset($calorie)){
    $as5=$calorie;
}else{
    $as5="";
}

<?php
echo '<p align="center"> Showing results for&nbsp:&nbsp'.'Name'.$getval.',&nbsp'.'Course-'.$course.',&nbsp'.'Cuisine-'.$cuisine.',&nbsp'.'Type-'.$type;',&nbsp';'</p>'; 
echo ',&nbsp'.'Calories-'.$calorie;
```

its working fine and displying only id :
if i give like this id to concern table values name not displaying

```
$query=  Course::model()->find("course_id=$as1");
$course2=$query['course_name'];

$query1= Cuisine::model()->find("id=$as4");
$cuisine2=$query1['cuisinename'];

$query3= RecipeType::model()->find("id=$as3");
$type2=$query3['recipeType_name'];
```

please suggest my suitable  answer

Comment: $query=  Course::model()->find("course_id=$as1");
$query is an object, not array, how can it possible to use it like $query['course_name'] ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I undertand your question, but, the find method return a [CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord) object with the first value who matches the condition.
Accessing to a column (field) is done by the "magic" properties of the object. There's a property for each column, so you can access to the 'course_name' column this way:

```
$query=  Course::model()->find("course_id=$as1");
$course2=$query->course_name;
```

See [This guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar), specially the ["Reading record" section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#reading-record)

Answer (score 0):

$Criteria = new CDbCriteria;

$Criteria->compare('course_id',$as1);

$query=  Course::model()->find($Criteria);

if(!empty($query))

$course2=$query->course_name;

$post=Post::model()->find('postID=:postID', array(':postID'=>10));

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar